Prove that the determinant of a matrix is zero under specific zero entry conditions
I am trying to prove the following:
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $A$ be any real $n \times n$ matrix. Show that the determinant of the matrix $A$ is zero if the entries $a_{ij} = 0$ for all $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$1 \leq i \leq k$ and $k \leq j \leq n$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$.
My Intuition:
According to the assumption, it always holds that $a_{kk} = 0$. Thus, the contribution of the first k rows to the rank of the matrix is at most $k-1$. The remaining rows can increase the rank of the matrix by at most $n - k$. Therefore, the maximum possible rank is: $n - k + (k - 1) = n - 1$ .
Since the maximum rank is $n-1 < n$, the matrix is not invertible, and hence, it follows that $\det(A) = 0$.
Is my argument valid?
